# _fcvt_s converting 0 value to string

Tags: c++, converters

When digging for a bug in an old C++ project I came to a (for me) strange behaviour of _fcvt
function to convert a double into a string

```
int decPos, isNeg;
char buffer[100];

_fcvt_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0.0000, 2, &decPos, &isNeg);  // buffer == "00"
_fcvt_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1.0000, 2, &decPos, &isNeg);  // buffer == "100"
```

I would expect that first call of _fcvt fills buffer with "000" instead of "00".

That caused the error I was looking for.
Is this a bug in _fcvt (e.g. caused by operating system or regional settings) or is it by design?
I'm using latest Windows 10 and VS2019

The workaround is easy by omitting that function:

```
double val = 0.0;
int numDec = 2;

std::ostringstream sout;
sout << std::setprecision(numDec) << std::fixed << val;
string test = sout.str();  //0.00
```

Comment: After reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fcvt-s?view=msvc-160) that behaviour sorta makes sense to me even though I've never used that function and probably never will. I'd guess `decPos` is 0 for the first line and 1 for the second.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is correct according to the manual.

> A zero or negative integer value indicates that the decimal point lies to the left of the first digit.

Inspect the decimal position in `decPos`. If it's 0, then you get .00 that is a correct 00 in the buffer.